# Is Super Saiyan 4 Vegito transformation the same Super Saiyan 4 transformation we know or it's an upgrade?

Tags: dragon-ball-heroes, dragon-ball-gt

So in Dragon Ball Heroes Vegito appeared after the fusion of Super Saiyan 4 Goku and Super Saiyan 4 Vegeta. But this Vegito has a Super Saiyan 4 transformation that sparks electricity like the SSJ2 unlike the original Super Saiyan 4 transformation. Is Super Saiyan 4 Vegito transformation the same Super Saiyan 4 transformation we know or it's an upgrade/ a new transformation?

Original SSJ4 transformation

[image]

SSJ4 transformation from Dragon Ball Heroes

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Both Xeno Goku and Xeno: Vegeta were in their SSJ4 forms before and it was more or less established as their maximum level of power. Hence, Xeno: Vegito here is indeed using the same SSJ4 form.

Answer (score -1):

It's the same SSJ4 the sparks were just there to show power kinda like the way his SSJ did the same back in the Buu saga.I'd link the DB wiki but i can't so maybe someone else can.

Comment: Why did i get a down vote ;-;

Comment: Your answer was not concise, it was more of a comment due to the way it was phrased.